# How to update a standalone APP by expo:publish?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have two standalone APP building by Expo, one for iOS which push to testflight so internal iOS users can test it, another is just an APK let Android users can download and test.

Like Expo document said, I publish code to release-channel 'staging' then build these two APP by release channel staging, all are good and my users can start testing with testflight/APK.

But when I modify code and publish again, no OTA update happen, and in my Expo dashboard, the version code is just the previous one (I've also updated version/android.versionCode/ios.buildNumber in app.json).

What should I do to make the OTA update works? If need any other information please let me know, any suggestion is appreciated!!

Comment: I've figured out what's happen...In Expo documentation it said : Change anything under the ios, android, or notification keys you need to re-build, and I've changed the ios.buildNumber & android.versionCode, which make the OTA updates failure.